# Flex box 3 column layout with sticky footer

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, layout, flexbox

Ive got a problem with flex layout I found [here](http://codepen.io/devtips/pen/wByQdO?editors=110). Its from [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1lREysgdgc) . The problem is that footer scrolls down together with the page, instead of staying at the bottom of the content or at the bottom of the page if there isn't enough content. What I mean by that is

[image]

The code is for React components but it is easy to figure out.

Any help much appreciated.

```js
//// All styles are in Layout component. 

///////////  LAYOUT START  ////////////////

class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    
    // STYLES START HERE
    
    const styleLayout = {
      siteWrapper: {
              display: 'flex',
              flexDirection: "column",
              height: '100vh'
      },      
      site: {        
              display: 'flex',
              flexGrow: '1',
              background: 'pink'   
      },
      siteContent: {        
              flexGrow: '1',
              paddingTop: '80px',
              background: 'lightgreen',  
      },
      rightColumn : {            
            width: '200px',
            paddingTop: '80px',
            background: 'lightblue'
      },
      leftColumn : {
            order: '-1',
            width: '200px',
            paddingTop: '80px',
            background: 'honeydew'
      }
    }
    

    return (
       
        <div style={styleLayout.siteWrapper}>               
            <Header />  
        
            <div style={styleLayout.site}>
                
                <div style={styleLayout.siteContent}>
                    dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
                </div> 
                
                <div style={styleLayout.leftColumn}>
                    <LeftColumn />
                </div>
                
                <div style={styleLayout.rightColumn}>
                    <RightColumn />
                </div>

            </div>
            <Footer />
      </div>    
    );
  }
}

////////////  COMPONENTS START

class RightColumn extends React.Component {
  render() {
  
    return (
      <div >Right Column</div>
    );
  }
}


class LeftColumn extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <div >Left dsargsrtdgfeadcsfdsColumn</div>
    );
  }
}

class Header extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)  
  }

  render() {
    const styleHeader = {
      background: 'olivedrab'
    }
    return (
      <div style={styleHeader}>
         <h2> Header</h2>
        </div>
      
    );
  }
}


class Footer extends React.Component {
  render() {
   const styleFooter = {
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    height: '100px',
    }
    return (
      <footer style={styleFooter}>footer</footer>
    );
  }
}

///////////  COMPONENTS END  ////////////////


ReactDOM.render(
<Layout />
  
,document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `min-height` instead of `height`

this

```
siteWrapper: {
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: "column",
          height: '100vh'
}
```

should be

```
siteWrapper: {
           display: 'flex',
           flexDirection: "column",
           minHeight: '100vh'
}
```

```js
//// All styles are in Layout component. 

///////////  LAYOUT START  ////////////////

class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    
    // STYLES START HERE
    
    const styleLayout = {
      siteWrapper: {
              display: 'flex',
              flexDirection: "column",
              minHeight: '100vh'
      },      
      site: {        
              display: 'flex',
              flexGrow: '1',
              background: 'pink'   
      },
      siteContent: {        
              flexGrow: '1',
              paddingTop: '80px',
              background: 'lightgreen',  
      },
      rightColumn : {            
            width: '200px',
            paddingTop: '80px',
            background: 'lightblue'
      },
      leftColumn : {
            order: '-1',
            width: '200px',
            paddingTop: '80px',
            background: 'honeydew'
      }
    }
    

    return (
       
        <div style={styleLayout.siteWrapper}>               
            <Header />  
        
            <div style={styleLayout.site}>
                
                <div style={styleLayout.siteContent}>
                    dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
                </div> 
                
                <div style={styleLayout.leftColumn}>
                    <LeftColumn />
                </div>
                
                <div style={styleLayout.rightColumn}>
                    <RightColumn />
                </div>

            </div>
            <Footer />
      </div>    
    );
  }
}

////////////  COMPONENTS START

class RightColumn extends React.Component {
  render() {
  
    return (
      <div >Right Column</div>
    );
  }
}


class LeftColumn extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <div >Left dsargsrtdgfeadcsfdsColumn</div>
    );
  }
}

class Header extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)  
  }

  render() {
    const styleHeader = {
      background: 'olivedrab'
    }
    return (
      <div style={styleHeader}>
         <h2> Header</h2>
        </div>
      
    );
  }
}


class Footer extends React.Component {
  render() {
   const styleFooter = {
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    height: '100px',
    }
    return (
      <footer style={styleFooter}>footer</footer>
    );
  }
}

///////////  COMPONENTS END  ////////////////


ReactDOM.render(
<Layout />
  
,document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```

Comment: God damn it. I play with height on wrapper and the body. Shame I didnt figure it out myself. Thanks a lot. You saved me.

Answer (score 1):

if you want your footer stick to bottom of the page use this

```js
//// All styles are in Layout component. 

///////////  LAYOUT START  ////////////////

class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    
    // STYLES START HERE
    
    const styleLayout = {
      siteWrapper: {
              display: 'flex',
              flexDirection: "column",
              height: '100vh'
      },      
      site: {        
              display: 'flex',
              flexGrow: '1',
              background: 'pink'   
      },
      siteContent: {        
              flexGrow: '1',
              paddingTop: '80px',
              background: 'lightgreen',  
      },
      rightColumn : {            
            width: '200px',
            paddingTop: '80px',
            background: 'lightblue'
      },
      leftColumn : {
            order: '-1',
            width: '200px',
            paddingTop: '80px',
            background: 'honeydew'
      }
    }
    

    return (
       
        <div style={styleLayout.siteWrapper}>               
            <Header />  
        
            <div style={styleLayout.site}>
                
                <div style={styleLayout.siteContent}>
                    dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
       dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
                </div> 
                
                <div style={styleLayout.leftColumn}>
                    <LeftColumn />
                </div>
                
                <div style={styleLayout.rightColumn}>
                    <RightColumn />
                </div>

            </div>
            <Footer />
      </div>    
    );
  }
}

////////////  COMPONENTS START

class RightColumn extends React.Component {
  render() {
  
    return (
      <div >Right Column</div>
    );
  }
}


class LeftColumn extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <div >Left dsargsrtdgfeadcsfdsColumn</div>
    );
  }
}

class Header extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)  
  }

  render() {
    const styleHeader = {
      background: 'olivedrab'
    }
    return (
      <div style={styleHeader}>
         <h2> Header</h2>
        </div>
      
    );
  }
}


class Footer extends React.Component {
  render() {
   const styleFooter = {
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    height: '30px',
    position: 'fixed',
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: '100%'
    }
    return (
      <footer style={styleFooter}>footer</footer>
    );
  }
}

///////////  COMPONENTS END  ////////////////


ReactDOM.render(
<Layout />
  
,document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time. I actually was looking for a footer that stays at the end of the page/content, unless there is only a little content the it stays at the bottom of the screen. BTW, if you look closely your sticky footer works but the layout is still broken.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own [React layout library "Re-Flex"](https://github.com/leefsmp/re-flex) initially to handle resizable panes and complex nested layouts. This maybe an overkill for what you are trying to accomplish but could come up handy if one day you decide to add a resizable pane to your page.

One of the example in the [doc](https://leefsmp.github.io/Re-Flex/index.html) is a complete layout with sticky header and footer:

```
class ReflexAdvancedDemo extends React.Component {

  constructor () {

    super()

    this.resizeProps = {
      onStopResize: this.onStopResize.bind(this),
      onResize: this.onResize.bind(this)
    }
  }

  onResize (e) {

    if (e.domElement) {

      e.domElement.classList.add('resizing')
    }
  }

  onStopResize (e) {

    if (e.domElement) {

      e.domElement.classList.remove('resizing')
    }
  }

  render () {

    return (
      <ReflexContainer orientation="horizontal">
        <ReflexElement className="header" flex={0.1}>
          <div className="pane-content">
            <label>
              Header (fixed)
            </label>
          </div>
        </ReflexElement>
        <ReflexElement>
          <ReflexContainer orientation="vertical">
            <ReflexElement {...this.resizeProps}>
              <ReflexContainer orientation="horizontal">
                <ReflexElement {...this.resizeProps}>
                  <div className="pane-content">
                    <div style={{height: '30%'}}/>
                    <label style={{height: '0%'}}>
                      Left Pane <br/> Top
                      <br/>
                      (splitter propagation)
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </ReflexElement>
                <ReflexSplitter propagate={true} {...this.resizeProps}/>
                <ReflexElement {...this.resizeProps}>
                  <div className="pane-content">
                    <div style={{height: '30%'}}/>
                    <label style={{height: '0%'}}>
                      Left Pane <br/> Middle
                      <br/>
                      (splitter propagation)
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </ReflexElement>
                <ReflexSplitter propagate={true} {...this.resizeProps}/>
                <ReflexElement {...this.resizeProps}>
                  <div className="pane-content">
                    <div style={{height: '30%'}}/>
                    <label style={{height: '0%'}}>
                      Left Pane <br/> Bottom
                      <br/>
                      (splitter propagation)
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </ReflexElement>
              </ReflexContainer>
            </ReflexElement>
            <ReflexSplitter {...this.resizeProps}/>
            <ReflexElement flex={0.5} {...this.resizeProps}>
              <div className="pane-content">
                <label>
                  Middle Pane
                </label>
              </div>
            </ReflexElement>
            <ReflexSplitter{...this.resizeProps}/>
            <ReflexElement {...this.resizeProps}>
              <ReflexContainer orientation="horizontal">
                <ReflexElement {...this.resizeProps}>
                  <div>
                    <ReflexContainer orientation="vertical">
                      <ReflexElement {...this.resizeProps}>
                        <div className="pane-content">
                          <label>
                            Right Pane <br/> Upper-Left
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      </ReflexElement>
                      <ReflexSplitter/>
                      <ReflexElement {...this.resizeProps}>
                        <div className="pane-content">
                          <label>
                            Right Pane <br/> Upper-Right
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      </ReflexElement>
                    </ReflexContainer>
                  </div>
                </ReflexElement>
                <ReflexSplitter {...this.resizeProps}/>
                <ReflexElement {...this.resizeProps}>
                  <div className="pane-content">
                    <label>
                      Right Pane <br/> Bottom
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </ReflexElement>
              </ReflexContainer>
            </ReflexElement>
          </ReflexContainer>
        </ReflexElement>
        <ReflexElement className="footer" flex={0.1}>
          <div className="pane-content">
            <label>
              Footer (fixed)
            </label>
          </div>
        </ReflexElement>
      </ReflexContainer>
    )
  }
}
```

[image]